# Applescript to copy each file individually to target folder

Tags: applescript, automator

I have all these movies in .dvdmedia format and I want to covert them all to a smaller file size such as .mp4.

But what I need to do is create an applescript that will copy the individual file to a folder 'Conversion'. Once the file in the folder is deleted it copies the next item and deletes the previous.

I've completed an Automation script that once the item is added to the folder is starts formatting the file through TurboHD then deletes the file and moves the converted item to another folder 'Completed'

Does anyone able to help me with this?

Please note that the location of the movies are on a NAS drive

Answer (score 0):

there :) I coded the following. Please note to save it as an **Application** with **Stay open after run handler** checked.

You have to **set the source and the target path** to the paths in **your** environment.

Finally you have to set the **return** value. The value sets the interval in seconds to wait until next execution. If each of your conversions takes about an hour, I think I would check every 5 minutes meaning the handler has to return 300.

```
-- The idle-Handler defines a repetitive task
-- Note: Save as Application with option "Stay open after run handler"
on idle
    -- define the folders to watch
    set theSourceFolder to (POSIX file "/Users/myHomeFolder/Desktop/Conversion_Source") as alias
    set theTargetFolder to (POSIX file "/Volumes/myMountedVolume/Conversion") as alias

    -- check the contained files (get visible files only because of .DS_Store etc.)
    tell application "System Events"
        set availableSourceFiles to every file of theSourceFolder whose visible is true
        set filesOfTargetFolder to files of theTargetFolder whose visible is true
    end tell

    -- if no more source file is available, quit this script
    if (count of availableSourceFiles) = 0 then
        quit
    end if

    -- if the target folder is empty start move
    if (count of filesOfTargetFolder) = 0 then
        -- get the first item from source folder
        set sourceFile to (first item of availableSourceFiles) as alias
        -- use the Finder to copy the file
        tell application "Finder"
            -- duplicate the file to the target folder
            duplicate sourceFile to theTargetFolder
            --  move the source file to trash after copy
            move sourceFile to trash
        end tell
    end if
    -- the integer returned is the time to wait (in seconds)
    -- here: two minutes
    return 120
end idle
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg